# Error: Not allowed element when it is in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, xhtml

Just a quick validation question, I get:

**document type does not allow element "div" here**

And my code:

```
  $('#wrapper').prepend('<div id="slider"></div>');
```

It's just a JS stuff, how do I handle this?

Comment: Where in the document is this located?

Comment: Where are you getting that error, in the console or on W3C ?

Comment: What type of element is #wrapper?

Comment: @ryan It's located just before closing the body tag.

Comment: You have placed a div element inside another element that does not allow a div as a direct child, like an UL etc. Possibly, you forgot to close an element, and that is causing the error. Also, W3C normally does'nt read dynamic elements.

Comment: What is the DOCTYPE, what type of element is #wrapper, and what type is its parent node. A relevant snippet of the markup would help.

Comment: @NickSlash wrapper is a div.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any time you would get that error in the middle of a piece of JavaScript unless you are using XHTML, in which case the short answer is: **Stop using XHTML, start using HTML 4 or 5.**

The reason you get the error is [described in the XHTML 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8):

> In XHTML, the script and style elements are declared as having `#PCDATA` content. As a result, `<` and `&` will be treated as the start of markup

The latest version of the [XHTML Media Types note](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4) provides work–arounds:

> DO use external scripts if your script uses `<` or `&` or `]]>` or `--`. DO NOT embed a script in a document if it contains any of these characters.

and

> If you must embed the content, the following patterns can be used:
>
> ```
> <style>/*<![CDATA[*/
> ...
> /*]]>*/</style>
> ```

This is all rather a lot of effort, and just switching to HTML is a simpler option. Browsers are designed for HTML and their XHTML support is provided as an afterthought. If you get any benefits from XHTML it will be from using it with server side tools as part of your publishing process … and not many people are doing that.